# inline static constexpr vs global inline constexpr

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, inline-variable

Suppose that I have a few `inline constexpr` variables (named as `default_y` and `default_x`) in a header file and I decided to move them to a class that they are completely related to and mark them `static` (cause it seems better in terms of design).

```
namespace Foo
{

inline constexpr std::streamsize default_size { 160 }; // not closely related to the class Bar

class Bar
{
public:
    inline static constexpr std::uint32_t default_y { 20 }; // closely related to the class Bar
    inline static constexpr std::uint32_t default_x { 20 }; // closely related to the class Bar
};

}
```

So the question is will this make a difference in terms of how and when they are initialized at the start of the program (and overall efficiency)? Will the `inline` keyword in this particular use case force the compiler to add some guard for these two variables and make accessing them slower? Or maybe because they're `constexpr` there is no need to do those stuff at runtime since their value can be retrieved from the read-only section of the executable and then be assigned to them at the start of the *main* thread?

I built the program once with `inline static` and once with `static` and there was no difference in the size of the binary compared to the previous solution so maybe the linker generated the exact same code (hopefully).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing `static inline constexpr` variables should not impact efficiency in any way. Due to `constexpr` they're const-initialized at compile time if it's possible. `inline` keyword here is helping you to initialize `static` variable inside the body of a `class`. You might find this material on the `inline` keyword interesting: https://pabloariasal.github.io/2019/02/28/cpp-inlining/

Comment: Nice article. I found what I was looking for.